# Contextual type NSIndexSet cannot be used with array literal for Swift 2.x

Tags: ios, swift

I get the error in the 4th line below where I am trying to reload a section of the table. I also tried using `NSMakeRange([indexPath.section], 1)` but keep getting the same error.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            isSectionSelected = true
            self.tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], withRowAnimation: .None)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("serviceHistoryDetailView", sender: self)
        }
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reloadSections` expects an `NSIndexSet`, not an array of `Int`.

You need to create an `NSIndexSet` from `indexPath.section`. Then pass that `NSIndexSet`, not an array.

```
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: .None)
```

Comment: it was that easy. Thanks!